# React, Node.js EvenEmitting on Express route to socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sockets

I am using `socket.io` to emit messages to the client, I know that I could use the `HTTP` response form the express route to get this example done, but in the real scenario I would be emitting as I get data from an API.

However this example replicates the problem I have now:

When I click a button on the client, I make a get request to an express route, my intention is that the emit message gets logged as soon as I click, but I am having to double click in order to get the message printed.

server.js

```
import express from 'express'
import { createServer } from 'http'
import { Server } from 'socket.io'
import route from './route.js'
import { EventEmitter } from 'events'

const app = express()
const httpServer = createServer(app)
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  cors: true,
  origins: [`http://locahost:4000}`]
})
const myEmitter = new EventEmitter()

app.use('/route', route)
app.set('event', myEmitter) // Attach the event emitter to use on routes

const connections = []

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  connections.push(socket)
  console.log(`Socket id ${socket.id} connected`)

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket), 1)
  })
})

// Socket.io emit generator on an EventEmitter listener
myEmitter.on('my-event', (data) => {
  connections.forEach((socket) => {
    socket.emit('notify', data)
  })
})

httpServer.listen(4000, () => console.log(`App listening on port 4000.`))
```

route.js - Express route

```
import { Router } from 'express'

const router = Router()

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  // Import the EventEmitter
  const event = req.app.get('event')
  // Here I send the string to the EventEmitter 
  event.emit('my-event', 'Hello from route')

  res.send({ ok: true })
})

export default router
```

Client - React function invoked on a click event

```
// To get the message logged, I am having to run this function twice
const callRoute = () => {
  // Initialize socket
  const socket = socketIOClient('http://localhost:4000')
  // I request the express route with axios
  await axios('/route')
  // Then I want to print the message
  socket.on('notify', (data) => {
    console.log(data)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I needed to change things a bit on the client side only:

Instead of initializing the socket inside the functional component, it had to be outside of it, and then use `useEffect` to listen for the emit

```
// Declare it before the app
const socket = socketIOClient('http://localhost:4000')


// Main functional component
const App = () => {

  // Here initialize the socket.io listener
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('notify', (data) => {
      console.log(data)
    })
  }, [])

  // Also disconnect if unmounts
  useEffect(() => () => socket.disconnect(), [])

  // And now I can connect to the route
  const callRoute = () => {
    await axios('/route')
  }
....
```

Also if you want to emit to a specif client with this set up, for which I had a very hard time finding out, do this:

On the client get the browser `socket.id` and put it on state

```
const [clientID, setClientID] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
  socket.on('connect', () => {
    setClientID(socket.id)
  })

  socket.on('notify', (data) => {
    console.log(data)
  })
}, [])

// Then send the clientID to the route
const callRoute = () => {
 await axios('/route', { params: { clientID } })
}
```

On the route pass the clientID

```
event.emit('my-event', { 
  message: 'Hello from route', 
  socketID: req.query.clientID 
})
```

And on the server change your emiter to this

```
myEmitter.on('my-event', (data) => {
  io.to(data.socketID).emit('notify', data.message)
})
```